# Issue when animating modal component with a Portal using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to animate my modal component when the user opens and closes the component. The modal component uses a Portal to mount and unmount on the page, and I'm using CSSTransitionGroup from the react-transition-group library to animate the mount and unmount.

If I use a class based Component for the Portal, everything is working as expected. You can see my full working example here: https://codepen.io/jeffcap1/pen/eoQZgp

Here is the Portal snippet as a Class Component:

```
const portalRoot = document.getElementById("portal");
class Portal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.el = document.createElement("div");
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("Portal componentDidMount!");
        portalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
    };

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        console.log("Portal componentWillUnmount!");
        portalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
    };

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, this.el);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to change the Portal component to use the new React Hooks API, specifically useEffect, the content is never added onto the page. You can see the full example here: https://codepen.io/jeffcap1/pen/YMRXxe

The Portal snippet as a Functional Component using Hooks is:

```
const portalRoot = document.getElementById("portal");
const Portal = ({ children }) => {
const el = document.createElement("div");

React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Portal componentDidMount!");
        portalRoot.appendChild(el);
        return () => {
            console.log("Portal componentWillUnmount!");
            portalRoot.removeChild(el);
        };
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
};
```

I'm pretty stumped and would really appreciate any insight on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it works like that:

```
const {useEffect, useMemo} = React;
const Portal = ({children}) => {
  const el = useMemo(() => document.createElement("div"), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    portalRoot.appendChild(el);
    return () => {
      portalRoot.removeChild(el);
    }
  }, []);
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
}
```

pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGaEbw

You were creating `el` every render instead of once - that could be the problem, because second render was with `el` that is not appended.

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple fix!

How were you able to debug that the el was getting created too many times and overwriting itself, or is this something that you just learn through experience?

Comment: @jeffcap1 everything in function body is invoked every render, but functions can have memoizations inside them (like `useMemo`, `useCallback` and `useEffect` do) so its not as painfull and can keep references over time - that's why hooks are a thing.

Comment: you're a hero mate